# raw and psd files

Tags: raw

Can I store my raw files and psd files in separate folders. With Nikon D850 I have big RAW / NEF files but huge PSD files after working in Photoshop. It would be better to have them separated for the purpose of backup. If I can them separated, I would store RAW in a 'cloud' backup and keep my PSD files on my NAS. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Why would you think you _can't_ do this?

Comment: Your import and backup workflow is different from the edit workflow, right? There are as many ways to do this as there are photographers, though.

Comment: @mattdm, the obvious reason for thinking you can't do this is that the PSD file might contain some internal link that references the NEF file, and that the PSD will become "incomplete" without the NEF file. But, to be explicit, this isn't the case.

Comment: You trust the "cloud" ?

Comment: @Alaskaman you trust your own backups to be more reliable than those monitored by a corporation with vast resources of money, hardware and expertise, and a business interest in doing this effectively?! What's so special about the hardware you buy? All hardware fails. How actively do you monitor yours?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. There is no dependency between the two file types. (Unlike .xmp sidecar files for example - which need a corresponding raw file)